# How do I replace global RegExp matches with object literal values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, global, object-literal

In an attempt at simple substitution, I tried something like this:

```
var dict =
 {
 ...
 };

var selector = ("'$greetings' '$friend'").replace(/\$([^']+)/g, dict[RegExp.$1])
```

But only one of the matching strings was substituted with the value of the respective key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a function as the second parameter resulted in the desired effect:

```
var selector = ("'$greetings' '$friend'").replace(/\$([^']+)/g, expand)

function expand(match, offset, fullstring)
  {
  var dict =
    {
    ...
    };

  ...
  }
```

Which can be generalized into a tokenizer, such as the following:

```
/* Get all anchors with the javascript: URI scheme */
$("a[href*='javascript']").each(function () {
    javascriptURL(arguments[1])
})

/* Replace the javascript: URI with the URL within it */
function javascriptURL(anchor) {
    var hyperlink = $(anchor).attr("href").replace(/./g, replacer).substring(1).replace(/'/g, "");

    /* Class name for new window binding */
    var newWindow = "extWin";

    $(anchor).attr({
        "href": hyperlink,
        "class": newWindow
    });
}

/* Grab all text between window.open() parens */
function replacer(match, offset, fullstring) {
    var tokens = {
        "(": true,
        ",": false,
        ";": false
    };

    /* Consume everything after the left paren */  
    if (tokens[match] === true) {
        replacer.state = true
    }

    /* Discard everything after the first comma; also reset after a semicolon */
    if (tokens[match] === false) {
        replacer.state = false
    }

    /* Continue consuming or discarding otherwise */    
    if (tokens[match] === undefined) {
        replacer.state = replacer.state;
    }

    /* Return the consumed string or an empty string depending on the tokenizer state */
    if (replacer.state === true) {
        return match
    } 
    else {
        return "";
    }

}
```

> function replace(pattern:*, repl:Object):String
>
> repl:Object — Typically, the string that is inserted in place of the matching content. However, you can also specify a function as this parameter. If you specify a function, the string returned by the function is inserted in place of the matching content.

**References**

- [String Object: replace method - Adobe ActionScript® 3 (AS3 ) API Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace())
- [New regular expression features in ECMAScript 6](http://www.2ality.com/2015/07/regexp-es6.html)
- [Regexp.prototype.replace](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-regexp.prototype.replace)
- [Using A State Machine To Parse Tokenized Data In ColdFusion](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1863-using-a-state-machine-to-parse-tokenized-data-in-coldfusion.htm)
- [JavaScript: a state-machine-based lexer + recursive descent (LL(k)) grammar parser + abstract syntax tree (AST) + generator - bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3772069)
- [lexer/lexer.go at master · eczarny/lexer · GitHub](https://github.com/eczarny/lexer/blob/master/lexer.go)
- [The GNU C Preprocessor Internals: Lexer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Lexer.html)